# GitLab CE 500 error on some projects after updating from 16.1.3 to 16.2.7

Tags: gitlab

After upgrading GitLab CE from 16.1.3 to 16.2.7 on RHEL 7. Some projects are showing a 500 error while others are working fine. All projects are working when being pulled and pushed using git from the command line.

I have tried the following things

```
gitlab-rake db:migrate status
gitlab-rake db:migrate 
gitlab-ctl stop
gitlab-ctl start
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole
UPDATE projects SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
UPDATE namespaces SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
UPDATE application_settings SET runners_registration_token_encrypted = null;
UPDATE application_settings SET encrypted_ci_jwt_signing_key = null;
UPDATE ci_runners SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
TRUNCATE web_hooks CASCADE;
UPDATE integrations SET active = false WHERE project_id = xx
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

None of this fixes the 500 error.
If I were to restore a backup copy of gitlab-secrets. All the projects will work in the web interface but can’t upload any files to GitLab.
The only temporary fix is if users recreate their SSL keys and make a change in their project. OR if they migrate their files to a new project. Then that fixes the 500 error. But once I upgrade GitaLab again, the 500 error comes back for those projects.

Comment: Is there anything written to the server's error log?

Comment: No, nothing of use.

Answer (score 0):

try to update from 16.1.3 to 16.2.0 at first, see how it would be. If all ok, go to 16.2.7.